# Adapt Xcode 7 and later applications on iPhone X

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, ios-simulator, iphone-x

I know it's early to talk about it, but I've downloaded the XCode 9 final build with support for the iPhone X.

I have a problem, all my apps I created with Xcode 7 and then updated with 8.

I still did not use the single display, but I have a storyboard for both iPhone and iPad.

My apps have the default background and are displayed correctly in the storyboard, but when I use the simulator this does not happen.
I do not know if there is an entry or an option.

Can somebody give me a hand in courtesy?

Images below to better understand the problem:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That screenshot should be used as an example on *Why Storyboards are bad*

Comment: ok, so how can I fix it?

Comment: @mag_zbc Do not confuse "I can't architecture my storyboards properly" with "storyboards are bad".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable launch screen storyboard or add iPhone X resolution launch image to adopt iPhone X layout.

Source: Apple Developers Docs

Answer (score 1):

Two ways you are fixing the above issue.

1: When you using launch images,You should add proper sized launch images like **1125px × 2436px** which is a 3x image for **375pt × 812pt**.(for portrait)

2: Otherwise you should move to  **Launch screen storyboard** file instead of individual launch images.

Please also note the following link.It would be very helpful to you.

[iOS Apps Adapt to the iPhone X Screen Size](https://medium.com/@hacknicity/how-ios-apps-adapt-to-the-iphone-x-screen-size-a00bd109bbb9)

This way you can adapt app will automatically to iPhoneX device